# Group by multiple values Underscore.JS but keep the keys and values

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm trying to group the following array with objects:

```
[ { user_id: 301, alert_id: 199, deal_id: 32243 },
  { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 32243 },
  { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 107293 },
  { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 277470 } ]
```

As you can see it contains user_id and alert_id combinations, which I like to group. So I would like to have the following array:

```
[ { user_id: 301, alert_id: 199, deals: [32243] },
  { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deals: [32243,107293,277470]}]
```

Anyone knows a solution for this? With underscore's GroupBy I can group the values based on one key. But I need to group them, based on the combination user_id AND alert_id, as you can see.

I took a look at [underscore.nest](https://github.com/iros/underscore.nest), but the problem is it creates its own keys.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use [**groupBy**](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy) with a function that creates a composite key using user_id and alert_id. Then map across the groupings to get what you want:

```
    var list = [ { user_id: 301, alert_id: 199, deal_id: 32243 },
      { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 32243 },
      { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 107293 },
      { user_id: 301, alert_id: 200, deal_id: 277470 } ];

    var groups = _.groupBy(list, function(value){
        return value.user_id + '#' + value.alert_id;
    });

    var data = _.map(groups, function(group){
        return {
            user_id: group[0].user_id,
            alert_id: group[0].alert_id,
            deals: _.pluck(group, 'deal_id')
        }
    });
```

Comment: Solved my problem, thanks. Just to add to this. I just returned the keys as separate fields and the whole group for one field, works brilliantly with my angularjs repeaters.

Comment: Can I ask what the purpose of the number sign ( '#' ) is?

Comment: It's used to delimit the user_id from the alert_id so that the string returned in the groupBy function looks something like '301#200' (Javascript will coerce the numbers to strings). If it wasn't used then the function would return a number e.g 501 (301 + 200) which could be incorrect e.g. 300 + 201 === 400 + 101.

Comment: What if both the keys are lists, like deal_id: [32243, 3535, 242] and  alert_id: [200,4242,242] and need to groupBy all the items based on the combinations of these two keys? Stuck at this. Please help. @GruffBunny

Answer (score 0):

I would like to contribute a neat typescript ES6 group by.
I am not really sure how to tighten up the return value typing. Some trickery is needed there, but this works rather well for me.

```
/**
 * group the supplied list by a set of keys.
 * @param list the list of items to group.
 * @param children the key for the array of child items.
 * @param components the components to group by.
 */
groupByMultipleFields<T, K extends keyof T>(
    list: T[],
    children: string,
    ...components: K[]): any[] {

    var grouping = [...list.reduce((r, o) => {
        const key = components.map(_ => `${o[_]}`).join(" :: ");
        var keyed = r.get(key) || components.reduce((x, y) => { x[y] = o[y]; return x; }, <T>{});
        keyed[children] = keyed[children] || [];
        keyed[children].push(o);
        return r.set(key, keyed);
    }, new Map).values()];
    return grouping;

}
```

You will need to turn on the typescript compiler option `"downlevelIteration": true` to allow the `new Map` to iterate and return `values()`.

Answer (score 0):

For some specific task i had to to safe keys and values for it
So i made this variant (with clean js):

```js
/**
 * Group your items in array by multiple keys!
 *
 * @param collection
 * @param retrieveFunctions
 * @param compareFunctions
 * @returns {Array}
 */
function groupify(
    collection,
    retrieveFunctions = {attribute: value => value},
    compareFunctions = {attribute: (groupValue, value) => groupValue === value}
) {
    let groups = [];
    let keyValues = {};

    collection.forEach(item => {
        for (let attribute in retrieveFunctions) {
            keyValues[attribute] = retrieveFunctions.hasOwnProperty(attribute) ? retrieveFunctions[attribute](item[attribute]) : undefined;
        }
        let group = groups.find(group => {
            for (let key in retrieveFunctions) {
                if (!group && !group.keys[key]) {
                    return false;
                }
                if (compareFunctions[key] instanceof Function) {
                    if (!compareFunctions[key](group.keys[key], keyValues[key])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else if (group.keys[key] !== keyValues[key]) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        });

        !group ? groups.push({keys: keyValues, items: [item]}) : group.items.push(item);
        keyValues = {};
    });

    return groups;
}
```

Here the link on gist:
[groupify.js](https://gist.github.com/KartaviK/f33120a7db7b095339f3f8eaba126d20)