# Compare more than one properties in underscorejs uniq iteratee

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm using underscorejs uniq method.

```
_.uniq(
    [{ name: 'a', family: 't' }, { name: 'b', family: 'n' }], 
    false, 
    function (item, key, a) { return item.name; }
);
```

Iteratee function just return one property. But I want compare name and family to create unique list. How  can do that?

Comment: Have a look at the question [Group by multiple values Underscore.JS but keep the keys and values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550624/group-by-multiple-values-underscore-js-but-keep-the-keys-and-values/25551041#25551041) it may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
_.uniq(
    [
        {name: 'a', family: 't'}, 
        {name: 'b', family: 'n'}, 
        {name: 'a', family: 'd'}, 
        {name: 'a', family: 't'}
    ], 
    false, 
    function (item, key, a) { return 'n=' + item.name + ';f=' + item.family; }
);
```

It'll produce an array with only three objects:

```
[{name: 'a', family: 't'}, {name: 'b', family: 'n'}, {name: 'a', family: 'd'}]
```