# JSON Group By with respect to its value

Tags: jquery, json

I have an json like that mention below in which i want to break this JSON with respect to year which is appended in last

```
[
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "pakistan-2016"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "Headquarters-2016"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "pakistan-2015"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "USA-2015"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "Headquarters-2015"
  }
]
```

I want result like that

```
[
  {
    "name": "2016",
    "categories": [
      "Pakistan",
      "HeadQuarters"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "2015",
    "categories": [
      "Pakistan",
      "HeadQuarters",
      "USA"
    ]
  }
]
```

Do let me know how can i achieve this or is there any utility which can help me to convert this

Answer (score 0):

Try this block of code.

```
   var input=[
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "pakistan-2016"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "Headquarters-2016"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "pakistan-2015"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "USA-2015"
  },
  {
    "GroupWithYear": "Headquarters-2015"
  }
];
var output=[];
function checkYear(element, index, array){

}
input.forEach(function(value){
    var year=value.GroupWithYear.split('-')[1];
    var country=value.GroupWithYear.split('-')[0];
    var name=output.find(x=> x.name==year);
    if(!name){
        output.push({
            name:year,
            categories:[]
        });
    }
    var categories=output.find(x=> x.name==year).categories;
    categories.push(country);
});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: This link is working for me [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550624/group-by-multiple-values-underscore-js-but-keep-the-keys-and-values)

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps.