# How to filter an array with objects and nested arrays

Tags: jquery, underscore.js

I am trying to get an array ( from ) to become like (to). To exclude 'qtty' in matching array values I used :

```
_.isEqual(_.omit(val, 'qtty'), _.omit(value2, 'qtty'))
```

from http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual it gave the right result but I am not able to get the final result demonstrated bellow.

```
From = 
 0 {itemId: "121", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 29}, {comboId: 201, setId: 28}], addon: []}
 1 {itemId: "121", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 29}, {comboId: 201, setId: 28}], addon: []}
 2 {itemId: "121", qtty: 1, subitem: [{subitemId: 72, state: 1}], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 29}, {comboId: 201, setId: 28}], addon: []}
 3 {itemId: "141", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 26}], addon: []}
 4 {itemId: "347", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [], addon: []}
 5 {itemId: "347", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [], addon: []}



To =
 0 {itemId: "121", qtty: 2, subitem: [], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 29}, {comboId: 201, setId: 28}], addon: []}
 1 {itemId: "121", qtty: 1, subitem: [{subitemId: 72, state: 1}], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 29}, {comboId: 201, setId: 28}], addon: []}
 2 {itemId: "141", qtty: 1, subitem: [], combo: [{comboId: 201, setId: 26}], addon: []}
 3 {itemId: "347", qtty: 2, subitem: [], combo: [], addon: []}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25551041/5900874) thanks to Gruff Bunny who posted the answer, but it needed a little tweak to make it work with a more multidimensional array like my case.

```
function unify(orderData) {
  var groups = _.groupBy(orderData, function (value) {
    return value.itemId + '#' + _.map(value.subitem, function (subitemValue) { return subitemValue.subitemId + '#' + subitemValue.state ; }) + '#' + _.map(value.addon, function (addonValue) { return addonValue.addonId + '#' + addonValue.state; }) + '#' +  _.map(value.combo, function (comboValue) { return comboValue.comboId + '#' + comboValue.setId; }) ;
  });

  var data = _.map(groups, function (group) {
    return {
      itemId: group[0].itemId,
      subitem: group[0].subitem,
      addon: group[0].addon,
      combo: group[0].combo,
      qtty: _.reduce(_.pluck(group, 'qtty'), function (memo, num) {
        return memo + num;
      }, 0)
    }
  });
  return data;
}
```

The major difference here is mapping `_.map()` through each subarray to be able to group by a complex multidimensional array.