# Group array objects by first one field and then a second

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by, javascript-objects

This is another question about grouping objects in an array by mutiple field values, but in my case, I need to do it first by one field value, and then within each group by a second field value.

First, here is my starting object:

```
var typeData = [
0: {
  details: {
    circumference: 227.7655,
    diameter: 72,
    material:"SA-240 316",
    thickness: 0.5,
    width: 95 
  }
  item: "Plate, 0.5000 in x 227.7655 in. x 95.0000 in",
  label: "Cylinder #1",
  type: "shell"
},
1: {
  details: {
    circumference: 227.7655,
    diameter: 72,
    material:"SA-240 316",
    thickness: 0.5,
    width: 95 
  }
  item: "Plate, 0.5000 in x 227.7655 in. x 95.0000 in",
  label: "Cylinder #2",
  type: "shell"
},
2: {
  details: {
    circumference: 227.7655,
    diameter: 72,
    material:"SA-240 316",
    thickness: 0.5,
    width: 95 
  }
  item: "Plate, 0.5000 in x 227.7655 in. x 95.0000 in",
  label: "Cylinder #3",
  type: "shell"
},
3: {
  details: {
    circumference: 227.7655,
    diameter: 72,
    material:"SA-516 70",
    thickness: 0.5,
    width: 95 
  }
  item: "Plate, 0.5000 in x 227.7655 in. x 95.0000 in",
  label: "Cylinder #4",
  type: "shell"
},
4: {
  details: {
    circumference: 227.7655,
    diameter: 72,
    material:"SA-516 70",
    thickness: 0.5,
    width: 95 
  }
  item: "Plate, 0.5000 in x 227.7655 in. x 95.0000 in",
  label: "Cylinder #1",
  type: "shell"

]
```

So what I need to do is first group the objects by the `item` field value, and then group by the `details.material` field value. Using the example above, I would have two groupings:

- Two shells with material of SA-240 316
- Two shells with material of SA-516 70

Getting the first grouping and iterating through the first group is pretty easy:

```
 _(typeData).groupBy('item').forEach(function(value, description) {
  ... do stuff here
}
```

Where I run into problems is trying to get the second grouping. I have been able to get this working:

```
_(typeData).groupBy('item').forEach(function(value, description) {
  // Next, group by material, since there could be instances of the same item
  // (such as a piece of plate) with an identical description but different material.
  var tempMaterialData = _.groupBy(value, function(thing){
    return thing.details.material;
  });
}
```

and now I can loop through `tempMaterialData`. However, this seems sort of kludgy. Is there a better way I can get everything grouped as desired in a chained fashion so I just need one _.forEach()?

Comment: You can't use `key: value` syntax in an array, only in objects.

Comment: `_.groupBy(value, 'details.material')` should work if that's Lodash.

Comment: @4castle I tried a simple test on jsfiddle, using dot notation like that didn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/0632t76z/

Comment: @Barmar It [works using Lodash](https://jsfiddle.net/0632t76z/8/), but not using Underscore. I couldn't tell which library the OP is using.

Comment: @4castle I assumed it was underscore.js when I edited tags, didn't realize lodash also has `_()` to create objects. To OP, which library are you using?

Comment: But I think his real question is how to do the aggregation by both fields at once.

Comment: To group by multiple fields, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550624/group-by-multiple-values-underscore-js-but-keep-the-keys-and-values