# Transform a list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists with Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, dictionary

Is there a built-in Javascript function to transform a **list of dictionaries**:

```
const L = 
      [ { "day": "20201210", "count": "100" } 
      , { "day": "20201211", "count": "120" } 
      , { "day": "20201212", "count":  "90" } 
      , { "day": "20201213", "count": "150" } 
      ]
```

into a  **dictionary of lists** like this:

```
const D = 
      { "day"   : [ "20201210", "20201211", "20201212", "20201213"] 
      , "count" : [ "100", "120", "90", "150"] 
      }
```

? If not what's the simplest way to do it in JS?

(It is a little-bit similar to matrix "transpose" operation).

Note: here it's a transpose and not a groupby like in [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by multiple values Underscore.JS but keep the keys and values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550624/group-by-multiple-values-underscore-js-but-keep-the-keys-and-values)

Comment: using simple js [Most efficient method to groupby on an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: This question should be reopened. This is not even related to grouping of array elements. The second linked question is related but this is still different enough to justify a new question.

Comment: I changed my answer to work with an unknown list of keys

Comment: I changed my answer to make it a universal function, in the idea of your matrix function

Comment: 3) I changed my answer to make it a faster ( than any one else here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming all objects have the same keys and your array is not empty, this will work:

```
let D = {};
Object.keys(L[0]).forEach(k => {
    D[k] = L.map(o => o[k]);
});
```

There are certainly more efficient solutions but this is short and concise and not too bad in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly short and efficient method for general values.

```
L.forEach(o => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    D[k] ||= [];
    D[k].push(o[k]);
  });
});
```

```js
const L = [{
  "day": "20201210",
  "count": "100"
}, {
  "day": "20201211",
  "count": "120"
}, {
  "day": "20201212",
  "count": "90"
}, {
  "day": "20201213",
  "count": "150"
}]

let D = {};

L.forEach(o => {
  Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    D[k] ||= [];
    D[k].push(o[k]);
  });
});

console.log(D);
```

Comment: `map()` produces new arrays that you don't need. It would be better to use `forEach()` since you are only interested in the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think such a function exists, at least in vanilla JavaScript.

A simple, pure vanilla and clear to understand way of doing it would be like this:

```
var L = [
    {
        "day": "20201210",
        "count": "100"
    },
    {
        "day": "20201211",
        "count": "120"
    },
    {
        "day": "20201212",
        "count": "90"
    },
    {
        "day": "20201213",
        "count": "150"
    }
];
var D = { };

for (var dict in L)
{
    for (var key in L[dict]) 
    {
        if (D[key] == null) {
            D[key] = [ ];
        }
        
        D[key].push(L[dict][key]);
    }
}
```

This is definitely not the most concise or most optimized way of doing it, though it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can just restructure your array of dictionaries as such, and re-map it with [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

E.g. (The following practice requires to iterate the elements with `map` `N * X` times where `N` is the length of `L` and `X` is the amount of properties you'd want to have in `D`, **ignore this** if you have many properties you'd want to watch.)

But, this is the easiest readable approach that I'd want to introduce to you before the 2nd approach.

```js
const L = [{"day":"20201210","count":"100"},{"day":"20201211","count":"120"},{"day":"20201212","count":"90"},{"day":"20201213","count":"150"}];

const D = {
  'day': L.map(elem => elem['day']),
  'count': L.map(elem => elem['count']),
};

console.log(D);
```

Another approach I'd suggest is to use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), this is by far favored in your case as it's easily expandable by adding more properties to the initial array.

```js
const L = [{"day":"20201210","count":"100"},{"day":"20201211","count":"120"},{"day":"20201212","count":"90"},{"day":"20201213","count":"150"}];

const D = L.reduce((acc, cv) => {
  for (const propertyToGrab in acc) {
    if (cv.hasOwnProperty(propertyToGrab)) {
      acc[propertyToGrab].push(cv[propertyToGrab]);
    }
  }

   return acc;
}, {
  'day': [],
  'count': []
});

console.log(D);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const D={day:[], count:[]};

    for(const item of L){
    D.day.push(item.day);
    D.count.push(item.count);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const input = [{"day":"20201210","count":"100"},{"day":"20201211","count":"120"},{"day":"20201212","count":"90"},{"day":"20201213","count":"150"}];
 // Create a variable that will store the result
 let result = {};
 // Loop through the input with forEach
 input.forEach((element) => {
     // Loop through the keys 
    for(let key in element) {
        // Check if a key is not exist in the result 
        if(!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            // Then create an key and assign an empty array to it
            result[key] = [];
        }
        // Push the elemnts to the array.
        result[key].push(element[key]);
    }
 });
```